# Getting (#100) Error with currency URL

Tags: facebook-graph-api, oauth, facebook-apps

We are setting up payments for a Facebook app.  All is working fine, except running into a problem when associating the currency file graph object with the app.  Getting the above error, double checked that the object is valid via the object explorer, and the app token is valid as well.

Comment: Does it work when you access it by URL? The examples in the docs all use the URL, not the ID, when updating the app payment settings

Comment: wow, so I was using the URL of the graph object.  But I JUST tried the URL of the currency file itself -- and it appears to have worked!